My new alcove tubs walls will be more pronounced than the untouched sheetrock outside of the tub walls. How can i deal with this
Ok, I'm having a pro install the tile in my alcove tub enclosure walls.  Forgive me for not knowing all the terminology.  As per the Manufacturer I will be installing the hardi backer board over the tub lip.  I did not remove all the existing sheetrock outside of the tub enclosure.  The problem I'm facing is that the existing sheet rock wall will not be as pronounced as the tub enclosure walls.  What are my options to fix or deal with this shorter than ripping out the remaining sheetrock.  Is there a metal tile edge that is offset that can transition from the tub wall to the outside walls? Thanks in advance ☺️

PIctures will help understand the exact problem.   There is metal edging for the ends of tile. Schluter jolly is one type.  This may or may not be what you need.  The tile pro should be able to recommend a solution as well.
